# Cleanest way to work with localStorage in VUE

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vue-component

I am  trying to set value from v-for directive into localStorage. Right now  it says

`Storage ​ length: 1 ​ songs: "undefined"`

This is what I want to store when pressing the button:

```html
<article
  class="all-tracks"
  v-for="tracks in artist"
  :key="tracks.id"
>
  <h1 class="track-title">
    {{tracks.track.track_name}}
  </h1>
  <div class="track_artist">
    {{tracks.track.artist_name}}
  </div>
  <div class="track-album">
    {{tracks.track.album_name}}
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sg" @click="addToPlaylist()">
    Add to playlist
  </button>
</article>
```

P.S I would appreciate any comment on my code as I am here to learn and trying to write the cleanest way, yet I am a beginner so please do mind my mistakes below

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
name: 'SearchArea',
  props: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      artist: [],
      songs: [],
    };
  },
  
methods: {
 fetchMusic(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      axios.get(``, {
         headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
         },
       })
         .then((response) => response).then(this.setResults);
     }
   },
setResults(results) {
    this.artist = results.data.message.body.track_list;
     this.songs = results.data.message.body.track_list.track;
 },
   addToPlaylist() {
     localStorage.songs = JSON.stringify(this.songs);
    }
 },
  watch: {
   artist: {
    handler() {
      localStorage.setItem('songs', JSON.stringify(this.songs));
    },
    deep: true,
  },
},
}
```

Comment: Hi ! :) There is some not so useful code here. Could you please clean it up a bit ? Same goes for some formatting. Finally, could you please provide us the content of `this.songs` to allow us an easier debug ?

Comment: If you take the actual values of the object and try to manually do this in your chrome devtools, does it work ? :) Btw, do you want to store the content of `artist` or `songs` since there `setItem` is about `songs`.

Comment: I've changed to set 'artist', now it stores all of the results (all object keys from the api call) and not simply the one track with the button

Comment: So, you basically want to save an entity when you click on `Add to playlist` ? Do you want to save the `tracks` or the `artist` ?

Comment: I wish to save: 
` <h1 class="track-title">
    {{tracks.track.track_name}}
  </h1>
  <div class="track_artist">
    {{tracks.track.artist_name}}
  </div>
  <div class="track-album">
    {{tracks.track.album_name}}
  </div>` altogether. Ty, appreciate your help!

Comment: You cannot and even if you could, you should not store markup (HTML) directly into localStorage but rather store the object itself. Then parse it back in your template. So here, I can only recommend to your that you store `tracks`.

Comment: I just made an edit, you may find it interesting ! :)

Comment: Fantastic, you really made a strangers day! Having a closer look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: alright, here I am with a new code example. In this one, you can see a `playlist` implementation that may be useful to you. You will able to see a playlist logic:

- add a first user
- append a new user
- delete the whole playlist

Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/save-entity-to-localstorage-with-array-appending-r5b6z?file=/pages/index.vue

You basically just need to handle the duplicates and see when you load it in your project !

---

So, as told in the comments in your question, you cannot and **should not** store HTML directly into the localStorage.
You may store the object itself, and then use some logic if you wish to fill your template with the localStorage.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/save-entity-to-localstorage-3435l?file=/pages/index.vue) is a demo on how to:

- call an API and wait for it with `async/await` syntax
- loop on those results
- save a specific user to the localStorage

You may store several users rather than one, I don't know. But this is the starting point you should work on.

Here you can see on the screenshot, that it's saved properly into the localStorage [image]