# How to store an array in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a data property

```
 data() {
    return {
        playWord: [],
        baseWord: "",
        result: [],

    }
},
```

And response

```
   baseWord:"Amazing"
```

baseword changed each time I send new request in api.
I want to store each data in local storage and send string value to axios post method.

My post method is here,

```
 methods: {
    name() {
        var name = localStorage.getItem("userName");
        console.log(name);
    },

    async playInfo() {
        this.$axios.post('user_play_info ', {
                words: "test",
                score: "5",
                user_name: localStorage.getItem('userName'),

            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
},
```

i have been trying localstorage.setitem

```
 const testObject = this.baseWord
    console.log(testObject);

    localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

    console.log(retrievedObject);
```

how can I store my data in array? and send sting value through api response.

Comment: Hi, I've made a complete example on how to use an API + localStorage on my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66046473/8816585).

Comment: yes , and i have random value " baseword " form api which changed each time when i resend api request , i want to store each fetch value in my local storage as string & post in string object in my post method

Comment: kissu , sorry for asking . i am new in vueJs.  yesterday you solved a question "Generate random word form one string value in data nuxt js" . can i ask you related question ?

Comment: Feel free to add any details here for sure.

Comment: i am asking you my question in my previous question , it will be batter to  explain you.
can i do that ?

Comment: The previous question is answered and done. Let's focus on this one: you can totally reference yesterday's one and show us what you have in terms of code (if it is still related to `localStorage`).

Comment: i need multiple value from one string value. like "orange", and generate multiple like "ornage", "oregn", "ograne" . like fist two & last one character will be same it will change only others character & need one original value

Comment: yes , its related

Comment: yes. it's worked perfectly.

Comment: I have already accept this answer yesterday. (correction : Sorry I thought , I have already accept this answer (did check mark) , didn't saw). now it's done

Comment: Haha, I'm talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71915610/8816585) actually, on the current question on the page.

Comment: Sorry I thought , I have already accept this answer (did check mark) , didn't saw). now it's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example on how to work with an API + use localStorage properly in Nuxt

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="cleanPlaylist">Clean the playlist</button>

    <p>Items</p>
    <ul v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
      <li>
        <span>{{ user.name }}</span> ~
        <span>{{ user.email }}</span>
        <button @click="saveToLocalStorage(user)">Save this user</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log('json', json)
    this.users = json
  },
  methods: {
    saveToLocalStorage(user) {
      if (localStorage.getItem('playlist')?.length) {
        const currentUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('playlist'))
        console.log('current users', currentUsers)
        const newData = [...currentUsers, user]
        localStorage.setItem('playlist', JSON.stringify(newData))
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('playlist', JSON.stringify([user]))
      }
    },
    cleanPlaylist() {
      localStorage.removeItem('playlist')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

A codesandbox can be [found here](https://codesandbox.io/s/save-entity-to-localstorage-with-array-appending-r5b6z?file=/pages/index.vue).

You should have a good amount of example code + there are some `console.log` to understand what is happening. Of course, the browser devtools (`Application` tab) are recommended.