# cant access json object stored in local storage [object Object] in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have `fieldObj` which I need frequently. It comes from database.
I want to store it in localStorage.

below is the code I wrote which fetch `fieldObj` from database if localStorage don't have it.

When I try to access the json data stored in localStorage it just shows

> [object Object]

code is treating `fieldObj` of localStorage as string.

I need to access key values pairs stored in `fieldObj`.

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: JSON,
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('field-obj')) {
      axios
        .get('/api/u/record/', {
          withCredentials: true,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          response.data.forEach((el) => {
            if (el.COLUMN_TYPE == 'int') el.COLUMN_TYPE = 'number'
          })
          const fieldObj = response.data[0].fieldObj[0]
          this.fields = fieldObj
        })
        .then(() => {
          localStorage.setItem('field-obj', this.fields)
        })
    } else {
      console.log(new Object(localStorage.getItem('field-obj')))
      // console.log(localStorage.getItem('field-obj')[0].username)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try to wrap the thing that you want to display into a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObject))` to inspect the variable. There is probably an object down there and not a string or alike.

Comment: do you mean `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('field-obj')))` ?

Comment: when it fetch `fieldObj` from database it gives `{case index: 'varchar(14)', next visit: 'date', patient name: 'varchar(30)', prescription: 'varchar(255)'}`

Comment: Yes for the first question. So if you store an object in your localStorage, you will get an object back. Hence something like `localStorage.getItem('field-obj').prescription` may be needed.

Comment: Got it ! changed the way I was storing item in local storage from `localStorage.setItem('field-obj',this.fields)` to `localStorage.setItem('field-obj',JSON.stringify(this.fields))` and accessed it by `this.fields = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('field-obj'))` and it worked completely fine.

Comment: basically I was storing fieldObj inside another object , hence fieldObj was inaccessible; `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('field-obj'))))` worked completely fine too...

Comment: Yep, this is usually the issue with this kind of error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244510/discussion-between-ht006-and-kissu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting it in the localStorage like this

```js
localStorage.setItem('field-obj',JSON.stringify(this.fields))
```

and accessing it with this fixed the issue

```js
this.fields = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('field-obj'))
```

---

A more complex example could be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71915610/8816585), using Nuxt.