# I need to save single objects in LocalStorage, but i have the whole array saved

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I don't get how i am supposed to save only a single object a not the whole array. I am trying to create a movie watchlist. If I click "add to watchlist", the single object should be saved in LocalStorage. If I hit remove from watchlist, the object should get removed. I tried to write down methods to regulate all of that, but i guess somethings wrong. The data comes from an API request. Here's the code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="card" v-for="movie in movies"
            :key="movie.id">
            {{movie.title}}
            {{movie.release_date}}
            <button type="submit" @click="storeMovie" >
                Aggiungi
            </button>
            <button type="submit" @click="removeMovie">
                Rimuovi
            </button>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
    //Cambiare il nome con quello del componente creato
        name: 'HomeComp',
        data () {
            return {
                movies: [],
                movie: "",
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            axios
                .get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=###&language=it-IT&page=1&include_adult=false&region=IT')
                .then(response => {
                    this.movies = response.data.results
                    // console.log(response.data.results)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    this.errored = true
                })
                .finally(() => this.loading = false)

                if (localStorage.movies) {
                    this.movies = JSON.parse(localStorage.movies);
                }
        },
        watch: {
            movies: {
                handler(newMovies) {
                    localStorage.movies = JSON.stringify(newMovies);
                },
                deep:true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getMovie() {
                this.movies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movie"));
            },
            storeMovie() {
                if (this.movie.length) {
                    // push the new movie to list
                    this.movies.push(this.movie);

                    // store the data in localStorage
                    localStorage.setItem("movies", JSON.stringify(this.movies));

                    // clear the input
                    this.movie = "";
                }
            },
            removeMovie() {
                localStorage.removeItem('movie');
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
/*Inserire style componente*/
</style>
```

tried to parse ad stringify, but i think i'm doing it wrong in some way. Also written some methods, not working

Comment: I have given a similar [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66046473/8816585). If you want to remove a single item, I guess that you can take the whole object with all the saves and delete the only one not needed anymore, then save it back. Hope it helps somehow. Not sure that there is a more friendly way to use that in Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few observations as per the code you posted **:**

- As you want to store the new movie through `input`, `Aggiungi` button should come outside of `v-for` loop.
- For `removeStore` event, You need to pass the store id from a template so that we can filter out the `movies` array.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    movies: [],
    movie: ''
  },
  mounted() {
    // This data will come from API, Just for a demo purpose I am using mock data.
    this.movies = [{
        id: 1,
      title: 'Movie A',
      release_date: '06/12/2022'
    }, {
        id: 2,
      title: 'Movie B',
      release_date: '07/12/2022'
    }, {
        id: 3,
      title: 'Movie C',
      release_date: '08/12/2022'
    }, {
        id: 4,
      title: 'Movie D',
      release_date: '09/12/2022'
    }, {
        id: 5,
      title: 'Movie E',
      release_date: '10/12/2022'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    storeMovie() {
      const newMovieID = this.movies.at(-1).id + 1;
        this.movies.push({
        id: newMovieID,
        title: this.movie,
        release_date: '06/12/2022'
      }) 
    },
    removeMovie(movieID) {
        this.movies = this.movies.filter(({ id }) => id !== movieID)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Add new movie : <input type="text" v-model="movie"/>
    <button type="submit" @click="storeMovie()">
      Aggiungi
    </button>
  </div><br>
  <div class="card" v-for="movie in movies"
       :key="movie.id">
    {{movie.title}}
    {{movie.release_date}}
    <button type="submit" @click="removeMovie(movie.id)">
      Rimuovi
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```