# how to for loop data from localStorage nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

this my code previously

```html
<ul>
   <li v-for="item in data.data">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

```js
export default {
  layout: 'main',
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const data = await $axios.$get('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    return { data };
  }
}
```

this can work but when i change the page and turnback to this page

axios send request again i need one time request and save data response to cache (localStorage)

now i try this code

```js
export default {
  layout: 'main',
  mounted() {
    this.starter()
  },
  methods: {
    starter() {
      let room = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('game_room'))
      if (!room) {
        fetch('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => {
            localStorage.setItem('game_room', JSON.stringify(json))
            let room = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('game_room'));
            console.log('Response ', room.data[0].title)
          });
      } else {
        console.log('Caching ', room.data[0].title)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now this response data save to localStorage but i dont know how to use data to v-for like the my code previously

Comment: inside your last `then` function callback you do: `this.data = JSON.stringify(json)`

Comment: i try

`this.data = JSON.stringify(room.data)`
`<li v-for="item in data">{{ item.title }}</li>`

this dont worked 

Comment: Hi, give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66046473/8816585